# Processing ANTLR3 errors in C++ target

Tags: c++, antlr

How can I catch ANTLR3 exceptions in my grammar? I found a lot of Java examples, but I can't get C++ working.
For example, a have a following line in a grammar:

`func_expression  :   'lengthof' '(' longid ')';`

How can I process an error when ';' is missing?
I tried adding `catch` nearly everywhere trying to catch ANTLRexceptions as described [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Custom+Syntax+Error+Recovery).
I alse tried to override `displayRecognitionError()` as described [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Error+reporting+and+recovery).

Maybe I'm just doing this wrong. I'd like to get a simple code example for C++ target.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem you're having? Could you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to shadow

`displayRecognitionError(ANTLR_UINT8**, Parser::ExceptionBaseType*)`

function (it's not virtual) in the parser::context section.